# On the nature of mosaic specified by Schlafli symbol $\{p,q\}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, polyhedra, spherical-geometry

I was reading [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02569.pdf) on hyperbolic pascal triangle and the author stated that for Schlafli symbol $\{p,q\}$, if $(p-2)\;(q-2)=4$, it determines the Euclidean mosaic. For $(p-2)\;(q-2) <4$ a sphere is determined and for $(p-2)\;(q-2) > 4$ a hyperbolic mosaic is defined.

I cannot seem to understand how to draw these inferences. As a machine learning scientist, I did not have a formal training in advanced geometry and so would appreciate any references or assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to compare the angles of a regular $p$-gon in $\{p,q\}$ to a Euclidean $p$-gon to see whether there is angular defect or excess. If the Euclidean $p$-gon has a greater angle sum, the tiling is hyperbolic; if the Euclidean $p$-gon has a lesser angle sum, the tiling is spherical.

So let's compare! The angle sum in a Euclidean $p$-gon is $(p-2)\pi/p$. The angle sum in a $p$-gon in $\{p,q\}$ is $2\pi/q$. The difference between these angle sums is

$$(p-2)\pi/p - 2\pi/q = (pq-2q-2p)\pi/pq = ((p-2)(q-2)-4)\pi/pq$$

which has the same sign as $(p-2)(q-2) - 4$, hence verifying the statement you found in this paper.

Comment: Thanks. This is very. clear. Then it must mean that in hyperbolic geometry, the sum of angles around the center of a triangle is less than 360 degrees and in spherical geometry it is more than 360 degrees ? Is that true ?

Comment: The sum of all angles meeting at a single point is always $2\pi$, no matter the geometry of your Riemannian manifold. However, while the angle sum of a triangle is always $\pi$ in euclidean geometry, on the standard hyperbolic plane the angle sum of a triangle with area $A$ is $\pi - A$, and on the unit sphere the angle sum of a triangle with area $A$ is $\pi + A$.

Answer (score 0):

One walk through of the math could be seen in my blog [Hyperbolic Polygon-and-Tessellation](https://animadversio.github.io/academic_notes/hyperbolic-geometry#Polygon-and-Tessellation)

Some of the tessalations generated from it are showed here
https://animadversio.github.io/portfolio/hyperbolic-art

generated with this [repo](https://github.com/Animadversio/Hyperbolic_Space_Art)